# How much reputation does Community have?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Also, what all badges would it have? Yes, I know the Community user isn't a person, but I think it would be interesting to see anyway.

EDIT: Anthony Pegram found his profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community, but I'm still wondering about all the Community question and answer votes.

Comment: I edited Community Wiki -> Community user, because CW is a type of post, not a user, but I'm still not 100% sure that's what you meant.

Comment: @waiwai933, Well, I mean if it were a regular user, how much rep would it have from votes on its questions and answers.

Comment: 408. I don't know about badges, but Community [sure is a hater](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1480/obvious-downvoters).

Comment: @Anthony: Hilarious! But how does Community vote?

Comment: "Negatively." Oh, you probably meant the mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Community is a stellar user, currently with 410 reputation points. Community has also managed to earn a staggering 15 badges, including:

- Deputy,
- Citizen Patrol,
- Investor,
- Yearling (x2!),
- Tag Editor,
- Electorate,
- Supporter,
- Strunk & White,
- Civic Duty,
- Critic ([boy, is he ever](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1480/obvious-downvoters)),
- Beta,
- Autobiographer,
- Organizer,
- Editor

A round of apple sauce for Community.

Community is also active on meta:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Here he only has a reputation of 1, but he still has 12 badges:

- Organizer
- Deputy
- Investor
- Tag Editor
- Citizen Patrol
- Strunk & White
- Civic Duty
- Supporter
- Taxonomist
- Critic
- Autobiographer
- Editor

According to Community's own profile:

> Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

so this is where some of the votes come from.

The reason Community has such a low reputation on meta is because it pays for bounties on community wiki questions.  It recently "paid out" 300 points on May 6, 2011.  Like ordinary users, Community cannot have a zero or negative reputation so it shows as 1.

Comment: Have another 25 from me Community!

Comment: I understand badges, but how did calculate reputation?